# What does multi-gpu training in keras really mean?

Tags: pandas, tensorflow, keras, lstm

I want to train LSTMs on multiple GPUs.
After stumpling upon this article: (https://www.pugetsystems.com/labs/hpc/RTX-2080Ti-with-NVLINK---TensorFlow-Performance-Includes-Comparison-with-GTX-1080Ti-RTX-2070-2080-2080Ti-and-Titan-V-1267/#functionality-and-peer-to-peer-data-transfer-performance-for-2-rtx-2080-gpus-with-nvlink)

I found out, that the training speed nearly doubles with a second GPU. But I cant figure out (or maybe overlooked) if the writer uses model parallelism or data parallelism (or something else).

And what performance Increase i can expect from using 2 GPUs. (half the time?)

Extra: if it works like stated above, i wonder wether i can combine 2 different GPUs (without NVLink) like a 3080 & a 3090.

Note: I wont be able to use a NVLink.
EDIT:
@runDOSrun Float or double sequences (of around 1.000-15.000 rows & around 10-100 columns), 1-2M Samples

```
[ 89.319787 1.329743 99.234670 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
[ 84.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319    2.319787 ] 
[ 12.319787 1.329743 33.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ]  
...  
[ 84.319787 1.329743 49.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319    2.319787 ] 
[ 12.319787 1.329743 33.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] 
[ 33.319787 1.329743 23.329743 ... 52.329743 0.319787 2.319787 ] ]
```

Batch_size 8, 16 or 32 LSTM with these layers [700,700,700,700,64,32] On 2 RTX 3080 or 1x3080+1x3090

Comment: The answer to these kinds of questions is always: it depends. Unfortunately on a number of factors such as batch_size, data size, number of parameters, VRAM, implementation, model type. So while you might get some anecdotal opinions, it's hard to predict for your use case and you will simply have to find out by trying.

Comment: @runDOSrun Float or double sequences (of around 1.000-15.000 rows & around 10-100 columns), 1-2M Samples, (see edit above). 

Batch_size 8, 16 or 32

LSTM with these layers [700,700,700,700,64,32]

On 2 RTX 3080 or 1x3080+1x3090